# Breaking Ties using combinations in R

Tags: r, math, statistics, permutation, probability

I want to break ties for a majority/Plurality voting using the below logic :

1. I have two vectors vName and v2. v1 and v2 both character vectors and have 5 rows.
2. A tie happens if :
   a- if every row in vName has a different corresponding value in v2
   b- if two rows in vName have the same corresponding value in v2 and another two rows have the same value (different from the value picked by the two previous rows) and the last row has a different corresponding value in v2 that is different of the two different values picked by the previous rows (the two rows and the other two rows)

For example :
say,we have a vector :

```
vName<-c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5") 

v5<-c("John","Abraham","Isaac","Abraham","Isaac")
v4<-c("John","Abraham","Isaac","Isaac","Isaac")
```

the 2nd and 4th rows picked the value "Abraham" and the 3rd and 5th picked the value "Isaac" whereas the 1st row picked a completely different value "John".
if such ties happen (both scenarios) then move to the previous vector V (n-1); in the above case it should move to v4. the value with the majority vote in v4 is "Isaac".
I found a solution to break the tie for the first tie situation, but for the one mentioned in the previous example I couldn't.
I was really working on it for days now and I really need it. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use grouping and slicing in a data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
v1 <- c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5") 
v2 <- c("John","Abraham","Isaac","Abraham","Isaac")
    
df <- tibble(v1,v2)
# group by the v2 column, select the head of each group and then sort by the v1 column
ties <- 
    df %>% 
    group_by(v2) %>% 
    slice_head(n=1) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    arrange(v1)

ties
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  v1    v2     
  <chr> <chr>  
1 x1    John   
2 x2    Abraham
3 x3    Isaac
```

You can change the `slice_head` to `slice_sample` if you want to choose a random entry rather than the first.

Comment: Thank you but I want actually to know which value in v2 has the plurality/majority vote. for example : "Abraham" has two votes and "Isaac" has two votes and "John" one vote. I want to break the tie which one has more votes "Abraham" or "Isaac" thank you so much.

Comment: I suggest you edit your original question with a worked example so it's clearer.